# Tab bar background color did not get changed

Tags: android, react-native, jsx, react-navigation, tabnavigator

I am new in React-Native development. 
I am using **TabNavigator** from '**react-navigation**' for tab bar in **React-Native**, everything is working fine excepts tab bar activeBackgroundColor and inactiveBackgroundColor did not get changed in android.
Its showing blue color only like the image given below.

[image]

Code i am using is:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { PixelRatio } from 'react-native';

import { ColorScheme } from '../Resources/ColorScheme';
import {Fonts} from '../Resources/Fonts';

import TAB1 from '../Screens/TAB1'
import TAB2 from '../Screens/TAB2'
 /** */
 var FONT_SIZE = 8;
 if (PixelRatio.get() === 2) {
  FONT_SIZE=10
 }else if (PixelRatio.get() === 3) {
    FONT_SIZE=12
  }

export default FavoritesScreenTabNavigator=TabNavigator({
    TAB1:{screen:TAB1},
    TAB2:{screen:TAB2}
  },{
      tabBarPosition:'top',
      swipeEnabled:true,
      animationEnabled:true,
      tabBarOptions:{
          activeTintColor:ColorScheme.tabBarSelectedTintColor,
          inactiveTintColor:ColorScheme.tabBarUnSelectedTintColor,
          activeBackgroundColor:'white',
          inactiveBackgroundColor:'white',
          labelStyle:{
            fontSize: FONT_SIZE,
            fontFamily: Fonts.QuicksandBold,
            textAlign:'center'
          },
          indicatorStyle: {
            borderBottomColor:ColorScheme.tabBarSelectedTintColor,
            borderBottomWidth: 3,
          }
      },
  }
)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks everyone for help, but `style` did the magic for me.
It changes the tab color from blue to white (the color I want).
Found the answer from shared [link](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1485) by @Val.
Just adding these 3 line in the code changed the design:

```
tabBarOptions:{
      //other properties
      pressColor: 'gray',//for click (ripple) effect color
      style: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',//color you want to change
      }
  }
```

Now Tab bar looks like:

[image]

Posting the answer because it may help for someone.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used the TabNavigator by my self since yet but, as far as the documentation describes the `tabBarOptions`, `activeBackgroundColor` and `inactiveBackgroundColor` are only supported for iOS. [As seen here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#tabBarOptions-for-TabBarBottom-default-tab-bar-on-iOS)

I guess you have to add the behaviour for Android by yourself. There is a Expo Snack based on this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1388)

[Direct link to the expo](https://snack.expo.io/SkS6svUlW)

Comment: it seems like too complex for me, i have solved it in easy way, thanks for your effort

Answer (score 2):

Refer to github [react-native issue 1485](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1485), it's a bug (in)activeBackgroundColor not working on Android.

My workaround for this is to use `indicatorStyle` to simulate, example code:

**Note:** remember to add `...TabNavigator.Presets.AndroidTopTabs`, indicator may not work without this.

```
tabBarOptions: {
    ...TabNavigator.Presets.AndroidTopTabs,
    indicatorStyle: {
        backgroundColor: mainBackgroundColor,
        borderColor: 'rgb(189,189,189)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderBottomWidth: 0,
        borderRadius: 5,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
    }
}
```

It looks fine in my project. (see Camera / NVR tabs)

[image]

Comment: @AjeetChoudhary Why not work? since I've done with Android (and with snapshot), there must be something can do with it.

Comment: I do not know why is not work, may be something was wrong. I did try in three different devices. Then i found the another answer in the link shared by you,, it worked for me..thanks

Answer (score 2):

I update [Val's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48091567/6280902).

```
 tabBarOptions:{
      //other properties
      pressColor: 'gray',//for click (ripple) effect color
      style: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',//color you want to change
      },
      indicatorStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'your indicator background color',
        height: '100%',
        borderBottomColor: 'your indicator bottom bar color',
        borderBottomWidth: 1
      },
  }
```

the hack is `height` value!